# How can I implement SIG_IGN or SIG_DFL programmactically in C/C++?

Tags: c++, linux, signals

I want to encapsulate the signal handling mechanism into C++ class like WndProc's message dispatching to children's window(s).

```
class SignalHost : public IRefCount {
private:
    SignalHost() { ... (init) ... }
    ~SignalHost() { ... (restore all signals) ... }

public:
    static SignalHost* getSingleton() {
        static SignalHost _instance;
        return &_instance;
    }

public:
    bool attach(SignalHandler* handler, int signum) { 
        ... (create a list for signal or push newbie) ...
    }
    bool detach(SignalHandler* handler, int signum) { 
        ... (remove the handler from list) ...
    }

public: /* when the signal occured, 
    this will invoke all of attached handlers for that signal. */
};
```

unfortunately, some handler requires special action such as SIG_IGN, SIG_DFL or SIG_ERR. for example, `nohup` uses SIG_IGN for ignoring SIGHUP.
and many cases can be occurred against the `SignalHost`.

1. Signal Handler A executed against SIGSEGV: 
   this will perform `printf("SIGSEGV!\n");`only.
2. Signal Handler B executed against SIGSEGV
   this want to bypass the flow into SIG_DFL or handle it like SIG_DFL.

in linux system, the defined signal handlers are just a dummy reference like `#define SIG_DFL ((sighandler_t) 0)`. i already know mechanisms about using directly with SIG_IGN, SIG_DFL or SIG_ERR. but if the signal handlers must be organized within some class and executed as series?

please look at the code below which express my question more detail without OOP concepts.

```
void my_sigsegv_handler (int signo);

...

struct sigaction sa_sigsegv;
sa_sigsegv.sa_handler = my_sigsegv_handler;
sa_sigsegv.sa_flags = 0;

sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa_sigsegv, 0);

...

void my_sigsegv_handler (int signo) {
    ... (handle SIGSEGV as my wish which must be executed) ...

    // unfortunately, my code can not handle it correctly...
    // so, I want to perform printing errors into stdin without 
    //    returning back into the flow which has caused errors.

    exit(-1);
}
```

Of course, specifying SIG_IGN into SIGSEGV will not be working as my want.
just, this code is an example for explaining i want to do.

**Question which i really want to know is,** How can I implement the handler which can work like SIG_DFL, SIG_IGN or SIG_ERR after above handler's code??

Comment: You are not allowed to do much in a signal handler, [there are strict limitations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal) including not allowed to call library functions. So `printf` would be ruled out.